# Python-Replace nan value to null in a tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to replace "nan" value to "null" in a tuple.

Example:

```
tuples = [tuple(x) for x in data.values]
tuples=[(10001, nan, 'test1'), (10002, 35.0, 'test2')]
```

Expected: (null without quotes)

```
tuples=[(10001, null, 'test1'), (10002, 35.0, 'test2')]
```

Comment: @VanPeer Its probably a numpy array, which supports `nan` values.

Comment: Hi, I am creating tuples from CSV file and using executemany option insert the data into Database, but if any value is blank in the CSV, DataFrame converts as nan. When I insert this data into database having issue nan vs NULL.

Answer (score 2):

If you test a value with `math.isnan()` you can find nan values like:

#### Code:

```
import math
import json

tuples = [(10001, float('nan'), 'test1'), (10002, 35.0, 'test2')]
new_tuples = [
    tuple(None if isinstance(i, float) and math.isnan(i) else i for i in t)
    for t in tuples
]

print(tuples)
print(json.dumps(new_tuples))
```

#### Results:

```
[(10001, nan, 'test1'), (10002, 35.0, 'test2')]
[[10001, null, "test1"], [10002, 35.0, "test2"]]
```

Comment: Is it possible test1 and test2 as single quotes instead of double quotes. If I want to insert into DB its a problem.